# Commandline programming

Tags: java, linux, command-line

I am using RHEL. I am just running the following program to print a line in my console,

```
   package test;

   public class test
   { 
     public static void main(String a[])
     {
       System.out.println("hi");  
     }
   }
```

I compiled it using,

```
   javac test.java
```

I tried to run,

```
  java test.test
```

It says,

```
could not load or find main class
```

I am in the directory where my class file is present.

```
  ls
```

on the directory shows,

```
  test.java    test.class
```

What could be the reasons?

```
  java test
```

says,

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: test/test)
```

Comment: 1. Shouldn't `test` fail to compile?  You're calling functionality outside of a method or `static` block context. 2. Don't you need a `public static void main(String[] args){ ... }` method? [For exampe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/)

Comment: omg I missed to type it

Comment: Downvoter, i corrected it. Any other reasons

Comment: test.class must be in a folder called test for the package test.. pretty obvious!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `.java` files should be stored within the `test` directory (`test/test.java`)
2. If you are using `javac test.java`, then make sure you change directories to the parent directory (`cd ..`) before executing `java test.test`, as Java will look for the `test.class` in the `test` directory (or package)

Take a closer look at [Lesson: Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/) for more details.

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: What part? Did you place the `.java` in the correct directory?  Did you execute the class file from the parent directory of the top level package? I would have thought [Managing Source and Class Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) would have been of some help explaing the requirements of the details of the answer...

Comment: @GopsAB I'm not sure about the downvoting of the answer, some people are very particular about "simple" mistakes, especially when they could either be solved through the use of appropriate tutorials or if the question is commonly asked (and yes, this just asked a few times a month)

Comment: If i have org.myorg as my package, then test.java should be inside org/myorg/test.java and test.class must be also in the same directory. Then i should run it from parent directory of org. Am i clear man?

Comment: @GopsAB Yep, that's the basics.  The `package` denotes the expected directory that the class file is expected to be in

Comment: Yes. But i haven't tried it before from cmd line. I just use netbeans ide and shortcuts. So i haven't come across this problem. Anyway thanks man

Answer (score 2):

`java` takes a *class name* (including package) as the argument, not a filename.

Also, the class `test.test` must be stored in `test/test.class` - *not* in `test.class` in the current directory.

You should have `test.class` inside a folder called `test`; go to the *outer folder* (the one that contains `test`) and run:

```
java test.test
```

Comment: java test.test says no class found.

Comment: @GopsAB what is your folder structure and what is the current directory when you run the command?

Comment: I am in CDH directory where my .java and .class files are present. I tried in the same directory all the commands from writing file to running it

Comment: @GopsAB You `test.java` file MUST be stored in a `test` directory.  You can change to the `test` directory and compile your `test.java` using `javac test.java`, but you MUST change to the parent directory (above the `test` directory) in order to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do for a simple java program:

1. No `package xxx;` line
2. Make sure the name of main class is `Test` - initial capitalized

Comment: Storing classes in the default package is not recommended as it can make then unassessable.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's only not recommended for programs complex enough to be split into multiple packages.

Comment: @immibis And if you never ever want anything to ever load those classes ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You can load classes from the default package with reflection or bytecode manipulation.

Comment: @immibis Oh flippen joy, so instead of doing the right thing, we make a hack around it...

Comment: @immibis So now we have a due inconsistency in the answer, we're insisting that the OP follow suggest coding conventions, but it's okay to ignore them when it's inconvenient...:P - What ever happened to professionalism, I thought that's what SO was about?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, I interpreted your comment as "Use the default package if you *want to prevent* anyone from ever loading those classes", not "Don't use the default package if you have anything that needs to load those classes."

Comment: @immibis Yeah, it's more along the lines of avoiding any other issues, suggesting the use of the default package "could" cause more issues for the OP, hence, better to just avoid it - but that's just me, hence no downvote (from me)